# How to using "\n" in message

Tags: python, discord.py

As what the title mentioned, i confused how to use `\n` in message argument for command in `discord.py`. As you can see, the below one is code that I made for sending/ whispering someone in the server by DM.

```
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='whisper', description='Whisper someone', guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def whisper(self, ctx, member:discord.Member, message:str):
    if ctx.author.id != 385053392059236353:
        if member.id == 385053392059236353:
            await member.send(f"{message}, from {ctx.author.name}")
            await ctx.send("Message sent!", hidden=True)
        else:
            await member.send(f"{message}")
            await ctx.send("Message sent!", hidden=True)
    else:
        await member.send(f"{message}")
        await ctx.send("Message sent!", hidden=True)
```

This is the layout : [image]

And this is what I want to do : [image]
How to implement that?

Comment: What does `385053392059236353` mean?

Comment: It's a discord user ID

Comment: To be clear: what you want is that if the user types a backslash followed by a letter n in the `message`, then it will be replaced by a newline when the bot sends the message? Then the answer is that this has nothing to do with Discord - you do it the same way that you would replace that text in any other string that you got any other way.

Comment: If what you want is what KarlKnechtel guessed, please [edit] your post to include the code you've tried, to replace the "\n"s with newlines.